# bar_index of specific timestamp

Tags: pine-script

I want to find the numbers of bars between a specific date and today's date(not current bar date).

This value should be constant at any bar.
So far I can only think of a solution where I compute this information only at the end, after going through all intermediate bars.

What I tried:

```
var savedIndex = 0
if time == inputDateTime
   savedIndex = bar_index

if barstate.islast
  num_bars = bar_index - savedIndex // need this as a constant
  label.new(bar_index, 0, "# bars: " + tostring(num_bars))
```

Ideally I want to compute this as

```
var num_bars = barIndex(timenow) - barIndex(inputDate)
// looking for a function like barIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ts = timestamp(2021, 5, 21, 12, 00)

bartime = int(change(time))

bars = floor((timenow - ts) / bartime)
```

This is might be as close as you will get, however it will only work on crypto, 24/7 markets. I'm not sure it would be possible to do this for other markets due to the temporal gaps from weekends, holidays etc.

Comment: Thanks @rumpypumpydumpy, but this is not what I want. I want the `count` value to be constant throughout. At any bar, I need to use the same value, viz. the number of bars between `today`(not current bar time) and the `ts`.

Comment: I see, it may not be possible, updated the answer with one possible solution

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently doing something similar.
Ideal solution is only possible if PineScript exposes an API to access future bars, not just history. Like `barsuntil` similar to `barssince`.

Answer (score 1):

```
getBarIndexAtTime(int _time_point) =>
    int m_bar_ind = an
    for count = 0 to 5000
        if time[count] >= _time_point and time[count + 1] < _time_point
            m_bar_ind := count
            break
    // @returns
    m_bar_ind

// How to use
m_date = timestamp("05 Jan 2023")
int bars = getBarIndexAtTime(_time_point = m_date)
```

This function convert time stamp to bar index. But it will work in your case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).